# checking for collision between circle and path (canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, game-physics

I need to see if part of a circle touches a certain path. The path also has a width of 20. 
Currently, I'm creating a circle with a radius of 20 every 4 pixels of the path and checking if any of these circles touch the other circles but this is a performance nightmare and I'm sure there is a better way to do this.

Comment: What path? Please add more info.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using your numbers because you don't post any code.
In order to detect collision between 2 circles you need to check if the distance between the 2 circles is `<= R + r + lineWidth`. In this case I'm using a very wide semitransparent stroke, because in this way you may see how the stroke lays over the circle: half inside and half outside.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let cw = canvas.width = 300;
  
let ch = canvas.height = 300;

let c = {}
c.x = cw / 2;
c.y = ch / 2;

let R = 50;
let r = 20;
let lineWidth = 30;
let m = {x:-100,y:-100}

ctx.fillStyle = "#d9d9d9";
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,.5)"
ctx.lineWidth = 30;

// main circle
drawCircle(c.x,c.y,R);


canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",(evt)=>{
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch)
  m = oMousePos(canvas, evt);
  drawCircle(c.x,c.y,R);
  drawCircle(m.x,m.y,r);
  
  if(dist(c, m) <= R + r + lineWidth){output.innerHTML = "collision"}else{output.innerHTML = ""}
});


function drawCircle(cx,cy,r){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx,cy,r,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
}


function dist(p1, p2) {
  let dx = p2.x - p1.x;
  let dy = p2.y - p1.y;
  return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}


function oMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return { //objeto
    x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
    y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border:1px solid #d9d9d9;
  margin:0 auto;
}
p{min-height:1.5em;}
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: thanks, I know how to check for collision between two circles, I was asking about the collision between a circle and a path with a width (20px in my example).

Comment: In this case please update your question and add some code showing what you have.

Comment: Beware, the correct check is *distance between the 2 circles is <= R + r + (lineWidth1 /2) + (lineWidth2/2))*, strokes bleed on each side, so only half of it will get *out* of the shape. In your case it is the same (because same lineWidth), but it is misleading.